# Collecting data from different dropdown menus php

Tags: php, forms, select, input

In my html form I have 3 dropdown menus for date of birth, day menu, month menu and year menu.

I want to collect day value from day menu,
   month value from month menu,
   year from year menu.

in php file I wrote for collecting the date of birth data; but it didn't work.

```
$date = $_POST['day'] . "-" . $_POST['month'] . "-" . $_POST['year'];
```

Help please.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Show us some code of your html form.

Comment: And what is that you want? How to write php file, how to write html code, or what exactly?

Comment: PHP code seems fine, have you set html forms method to post and name of form elements correctly? It will be helpful if you post HTML part also.

Answer (score 2):

a simple example for you too learn from :)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>date example</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['day']) && isset($_POST['month']) && isset($_POST['year'])){
    echo 'You selected: '.$_POST['day'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['year'];
}
?>

<form method="POST" action="">
  <p><select size="1" name="day">
  <?php formDay(); ?>
  </select>-
  <select size="1" name="month">
  <?php formMonth(); ?>
  </select>-
  <select size="1" name="year">
  <?php formYear(); ?>
  </select> <input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
//functions to loop day,month,year
function formDay(){
    for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>'."\n";
    }
}

function formMonth(){
    $month = strtotime('2011-01-01');
    $end = strtotime('2012-01-01');
    while($month < $end){
        echo '<option value="'.date('F', $month).'">'.date('F', $month).'</option>'."\n";
        $month = strtotime("+1 month", $month);
    }
}

function formYear(){
    for($i=1980; $i<=date('Y'); $i++){
        echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>'."\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems either you didn't post the data (did you use action="post"?) or the selects don't have a name attribute. But if neither fixes solve your problem, maybe you could post the rest of your PHP code and your HTML code too.

Comment: Yes I use action post and name of the selects are day, month and year. When I use this code in my database I see that it wrote 1. but what I want to see is 14-Feb-2005 for example

Comment: It *could* be a database problem too. What do you get when you just echo the values. Tip: use `var_dump`. It will allow you to echo variables including meta information, like the type and the length. You can also var_dump $_POST and $_GET to check if you see your values anywhere there. And, because it is just for debugging, you can easiliy trace all occurences of `var_dump` to eliminate them from production code.

Comment: It gets the values like 1964 13 04, for 13 april 1964. However with my code in the mysql database still it shows "1" for the date of birth.

Comment: @mertcek  What is column type of where you are storing data? Is it text or varchar?