# How to INSERT multiple HTML form fields into a single MySQL column as date

Tags: php, mysql, forms

#### Problem:

I'm having trouble finding the documentation or both relevant and answered answers to my situation.

Basically, I'm wanting to generate a MySQL-ready date ready for insertion by using multiple html form dropdown fields.

Currently my insertion code uses a single field for the date, which I enter manually in a text field in MySQL format:

```
$sql=
    " INSERT INTO events (e_date, e_time, e_ampm, e_type, e_name) " .
    " VALUES ('{$form_e_date}','{$form_e_time}', '{$form_e_ampm}', '{$form_e_type}','{$form_e_name}')";
```

Instead of $form_e_date (which I currently enter in text field using format YYYY-MM-DD), I want to use 3 separate form fields (such as $month, $day, $year) with values selected from dropdown select boxes.

#### Question:

Is there a way to concatentate 3 variables ($year, $month, $day, delineated with "-" for MySQL) in place of the $form_e_date, and if so, how would you structure this syntax?

I'm also open to approaching this a better way (still using MySQL/PHP); I just need help or direction towards the resources.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

#### Additional info:

P.S. The current syntax is

```
VALUES ('{$form_e_date}','{$form_e_time}', ... etc.
```

instead of

```
VALUES ('$_POST[form_e_date]','$_POST[form_e_time]', ... etc.
```

as part of a PHP fix to Undefined index notices I had been getting.

Also, the solution

```
$form_e_date= $_POST['year'] . "-" . $_POST['month'] . "-" . $_POST['day'];
```

is not preferable to me as it is since it causes Undefined index notices on the new year, month, and day variables, even when they are defined beforehand using a technique that otherwise eliminates Undefined index notices, for example:

```
if (array_key_exists("year", $_POST))
                $year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["year"]);
            else
                $year = null;
```

Code #abc (for comment to JT Smith's answer):

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

$whole_date = array($year, $month, $day);
$mysql_formatted_date = implode("-", $whole_date);


$sql=
" INSERT INTO events (e_date, e_time, e_ampm, e_type, e_name) " .
" VALUES ('{$mysql_formatted_date}','{$form_e_time}', '{$form_e_ampm}', '{$form_e_type}','{$form_e_name}')";
```

Code #fgh:

```
<select name="month">
    <option value="01">Jan</option>
<option value="02">Feb</option>
<option value="03">Mar</option>
<option value="04">Apr</option>
<option value="05">May</option>
<option value="06">Jun</option>
<option value="07">Jul</option>
<option value="08">Aug</option>
<option value="09">Sep</option>
<option value="10">Oct</option>
<option value="11">Nov</option>
<option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>

<select name="day">
    <?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <=31; $i++) {
        echo "<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>";
    }
?>
</select>

<select name="year">
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day`? Also, directly entring variables into your query is bad and dangerous, check [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and parameters

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  At this point I'm not worried about injection, as I'm developing locally and I'm the only person using it.  Although I don't see how it would be particularly dangerous in my case as the field is being posted from a select dropdown, not text input.  I'll look into PDO as well, although I think this might be a bit advanced for me at this stage.

Comment: PDO is actually very easy, and after using it a few times you start to like it. And for SQL Injection it does not really matter if there is select or any other way of inputing data. Data can be send even without opening your page. It is good practice to try to prevent it even for local page

Comment: UPDATE TO QUESTION: Upon further investigation, I found this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164333/collecting-data-from-different-dropdown-menus-php) which seems to be doing the same thing I want, but I tried this and it still doesn't insert anything into the my e_date column (as date type it inserts 0000-00-00 still; as varchar it inserts empty).

Answer (score 0):

Concat them in php according to your requirement or you can use mysql concat function too

Comment: I'm unclear though as to how this would appear in MySQL, particularly with regards to in and around the {} curly braces.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to incorporate MySQL CONCAT_WS() on the VALUES line to concatenate $year, $month, and $date in place of the current $form_e_date?  I'm having trouble handling the syntax with all the curly braces, parentheses, and single quotes involved that I undoubtedly need in order to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to concat it within the mysql query?  Why not just concat it into a single variable and use that variable (as you do now) into the query?

```
$new_date = $_POST['year'] . "-" . $_POST['month'] . "-" . $_POST['day'];

$query = " INSERT INTO events (e_date, e_time, e_ampm, e_type, e_name) " .
" VALUES ('{$new_date}','{$form_e_time}', '{$form_e_ampm}', '{$form_e_type}','{$form_e_name}')";
```

Comment: I tried this way before I posted my question, but the problem I get with this solution is Undefined index notices on the year, month, and day variables, even when I define them beforehand with `if (array_key_exists("year", $_POST))
     $year = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["year"]);
    else
     $year = null;`

Comment: Is your field in MySQL for this date field a `date` or do you have it set as a `VARCHAR`?  If you have it set as `DATE` then yes, you will get an error using this method.  I have my `DATE` fields set as `VARCHAR`.  Easier to work with, only downside is you can't calculate the fields records like you could with normal dates but this can be accomplished with some better functions, if you need the time/day differences in a calculation.

Comment: Yes the MySQL is a date date, but I don't see how this matters with regard to the notice, as the Undefined index notice is generated by PHP on the page before the has even been sent (or before any fields have been completed, for that matter).  And I do need it as a date, for calculation reasons.  I've discovered MySQL CONCAT_WS() and I'm trying to figure it out this way, or else I will eventually somehow.  Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: I was able to get ride of the Undefined index notices using an array() and an implode(), but now I've discovered that this concatenated date isn't actually getting inserted into its db column (although other single field values do get inserted).  Does this suggest an issue with the form?

Comment: what does the new query look like?  If everything else is getting inserted fine except the date it's most likely not the form but either the variable holding the date, or the query.  How did you change the date? Like I/we suggested?  If so, did you change the 'type' of the db field from `DATE` to a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: I added the new query code for you to my original question above in the Additional Info section and called it "Code #abc". But with both your suggestion (which I had tried before), I was too preoccupied with the Undefined index notices that I didn't even notice the date wasn't getting inserted either. I tried that (your) method and my new one both with the date as date and varchar, and in both cases date type inserted "0000-00-00" and varchar inserted empty in both cases. Any ideas? Also, just in case I'll add my form portion for the date fields (the ones that aren't inserting), Code #fgh.

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation operator in PHP is a dot `.` Syntax would look like:

```
$date = $year . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
```

Anyway a better approach would be to store the date/time in a single db field of type datetime. Check documentation for [date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and available formats.

Comment: I will look more into combining them all into one field (I know it's preferred), but first I need to figure out how to concatenate the fields using 1.) MySQL instead of PHP, or 2.) PHP that doesn't give me Undefined index notices on the 3 new variables even when I define them first.

Comment: A combination of `strtotime()`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
and `date()`
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
might do the trick

Comment: @ben, Do you mind showing me what this would look like?  I'm not familiar with using strtotime() function yet, let alone combining it with another function.

Comment: @Joshua it would look like this:
`date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("$year-$month-$day"));` but if you chuck it null variables you will still be in a pickle!

Comment: But to be honest that is no better than `"$year-$month-$day"."00:00:00"`